# Can't fill an array with doubles by user input, using a for loop. C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I recently started to study C#, now I'm trying to fill an array with doubles by user input, using a for loop for that. When I do it with Int, it's all good but with doubles I get the error message "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'."

```
namespace Homework
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] n = new double[10];
        double i, j;

        Console.WriteLine("Please give 10 numbers: ");

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}: ", i+1);
            //1st error
            n[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        }

        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element[{0}] = {1}", j+1, n[j]); /*2nd error*/
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

I got 2 of these error messages one points at the 'n[i]' in the first for loop and the other points to the 'n[j]' at the very end of the code in the WriteLine part.

Comment: Use `int i,j` instead of `double`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    double i, j;
```

Type of `i` and `j` should be `int` not `double`. Because you are using it as an array index afterwards. Declare them as `int` instead of `double`.

Answer (score 6):

```
double i, j;
```

Are used in your iterations. 
Those two must be integer since an array only has integers as indexes.

An array doesn't have an index `1,5`.

So, change it to:

```
int i, j;
```